# General topology proof exercise

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function between topological spaces. 
Prove that, if:
 $$(A \cap cl(B))\cup(cl(A)\cap B)\neq \emptyset \implies (f(A) \cap cl(f(B)))\cup(cl(f(A))\cap f(B))\neq \emptyset $$

$\forall A, B \subset X$ then $f$ is continous.

Also $cl(Q)$ is the closure of the subset $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Continuity of $f$ is equivalent to $f(\mathrm{cl}(A)) \subset \mathrm{cl}(f(A))$ for all $A$. 
So let $y \in f(\mathrm{cl}(A))$, and suppose that $y \notin \mathrm{cl}(f(A))$. 
There is some $x \in \mathrm{cl}(A)$ such that $y = f(x)$.

Now let $B = f^{-1}(Y \setminus \mathrm{cl}(f(A)))$. 
The intersection $\mathrm{cl}(A) \cap B$ is nonempty since it contains $x$. 
Now applying the hypothesis on $f$ leads to a contradiction.

Comment: How do you prove that $f(A) \cap cl(Y\setminus cl(f(A)))=\emptyset$?

Comment: I may be wrong but I think that $A\cap cl(Y\setminus A)=\emptyset$ is generally false. Take the topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$ induced by the distance $d$, where $d(x,x)=0 \ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $d(x,y)=1\  \forall x\neq y \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
Let $A$ be the open ball of centre $(0,0)$ and radius $1$, then $A=(0,0)$ and $A$ is closed.  $A\cap cl(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A)=A$